# "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" for only one column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I have one table `test` with 4 columns

```
id     name   visited      updated_at
1      abc    2016-03-20   2016-03-20 
2      xyz    2016-03-23   2016-03-23
```

When I applied below query

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE `updated_at` `updated_at` TIMESTAMP on update 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

It change updated_at if I change `name` or `visited`,

But I want to It changes only if `visited` changes.

How to achieve this ? thanks for your help.

Comment: Exactly my requirement :) Thanks for asking.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
drop table if exists `xyz1`;
create table `xyz1`
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    theName varchar(20) not null,
    visited timestamp null, 
    updated_at timestamp null
);
insert `xyz1` (theName) values('abc'),('xyz');
```

It is unhappy about our current NULLs sitting in there, error 1138:

```
ALTER TABLE `xyz1` CHANGE `updated_at` `updated_at` TIMESTAMP 
NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Let's fix that:

```
truncate table `xyz1`;

ALTER TABLE `xyz1` CHANGE `updated_at` `updated_at` TIMESTAMP 
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; 
-- works

insert `xyz1` (theName) values('abc'),('xyz');
select * from `xyz1`;
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | theName | visited | updated_at          |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | abc     | NULL    | 2016-06-16 14:39:38 |
|  2 | xyz     | NULL    | 2016-06-16 14:39:38 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+


update `xyz1` set `theName`='xyz Smith' where id=2;
select * from `xyz1`;
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
| id | theName   | visited | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | abc       | NULL    | 2016-06-16 14:39:38 |
|  2 | xyz Smith | NULL    | 2016-06-16 14:41:04 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------------+
```

See the manual [Automatic Initialization and Updating](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: How's this an answer? 
The OP wants the `updated_at` gets updated when `visited` is updated only.

Comment: this is *not* the correct answer: `updated_at` is <sic> updated when ANY column changes

Comment: on mariadb, it seems to disallow having 
`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` even on a single column...

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you need a trigger to accomplish that. Assuming your table definition looks like so:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test(
  id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  visited DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
);
```

... you can accomplish your goal of updating `updated_at` for only the `visited` column with a trigger, like so.

```
-- Create a trigger that will update the updated_at column iff visited changes.
drop trigger if exists upd_test;
delimiter //
create trigger upd_test BEFORE UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (  (old.visited is not null and new.visited is not null and old.visited <> new.visited)
      OR (old.visited is null and new.visited is not null)
      OR (old.visited is not null and new.visited is null)  ) THEN
    SET NEW.updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

And you can see it working with a fairly straight-forward example.

```
insert into test(name) values ("Bran"), ("Catelyn"), ("Daenerys"), ("Eddard");

-- this statement will not cause updated_at to be updated
update test
set name = 'Jon'
where name = 'Eddard';

-- this statement will cause updated_at to be updated, via the trigger
update test
set visited = '2016-06-16'
where name = 'Jon';
```

Comment: By the way, sorry if the conditional in the trigger looks a little wonky. For some reason, the null-safe operator (`<=>`) wasn't cutting it, and I had to manually check and handle the nulls. Not pretty, but it works.